# How to findFragmentByTag that is created in another Activity?

Tags: android

I need to find a fragment that was created by another activity that may be destroyed. However, it seems that when the activity is destroyed, the fragment stack is lost as well.

Is it possible to save the fragments created in another activity? Then re-use those fragments?

My use case is that I start at activity A containing A fragment, then it launches B activity containing B, C, D, E fragments. Suppose I go back and return, destroying B activity in the process. Is it still possible for B activity to find B, C, D, E fragments?

Comment: Fragments are tightly tied to its Activity, so my guess would be no, the fragments should instead be re-created,

Answer (score 0):

Fragment lifecycle is sync with its activity life cycle, for example, when activity enters stop state, fragment goes to stop state as well. If you want to use a fragment in your activity, you need to inflate it again.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

> a Fragment's lifecycle is tied to its owning activity, it has its own
>   wrinkle on the standard activity lifecycle