# Load a fragment once and show it on more activities

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an Android application, which has a lot of articles. If you open an article  a new activity is created. Now there is a part in the activity which is always the same, but it send a request to the server to get the data. I was thinking to make a fragment which will load the data only once (probably in MainActivity) and show it to all activities. Is this possible and how do I do it?

I also tried creating a fragment, but it still loads the data every time a new activity is created. Here is the XML code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <!-- There is more layout, but I don't think it is needed for now -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

And Java

```
private class getMessage extends AsyncTask<Void , Void, Void>{

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    DefaultHttpClient  httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("http:///www.example.com");
    HttpResponse response;

    try {           
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);        
        HttpEntity ht = response.getEntity();   
        BufferedHttpEntity buf = new BufferedHttpEntity(ht);    
        InputStream is = buf.getContent();  
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        total = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line + "\n");
        }          
    } 
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {} 
    catch (IOException e) {}

    return null;

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void args){
    try{
        textView.setText(total.toString());
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
}

}
```

And the code to add the fragment

```
FragmentManager fragMan = getSupportFragmentManager();
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = fragMan.beginTransaction();
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
fragTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_replace, fragment);
fragTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: When you add the fragment to the transaction, add it with a tag, say "MYTAG". Then when you create a new activity, search for this fragment using fragMan.findFragmentByTag("MYTAG"). And just add the fragment to the activity. I am not sure whether this will work or not, but give it a shot.

Comment: make all other activities child of main activity by extending Main Activity and get the value of your repeated part through a shared variable in Main Activity

Comment: @eric247 I don't think that is possible. Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319351/how-to-findfragmentbytag-that-is-created-in-another-activity

Comment: @Enve, my bad. I can suggest a small change in the logical flow of your code. Since all you need is the string "total", which you don't want to be received from the server each time. Why not pass this total value as an extra to every next activity. Your first activity wont be having this total extra, so first time you load it. From that point onward you check in each activity, if you already have the total extra, don't ping the server, just show that value.

Comment: @Enve If you concern is not to call asyncTask again and again for that repeating value this approach should work ,why do you want to use the same instance of fragment as in main activity  anyway?

Comment: @eric247 There is actually a lot more code (both XML and Java), but I didn't include it so the post wouldn't be too long.

Comment: @NavinRajPandey There is data in the fragment that needs to be loaded only once per session (but I must load it from the server). This fragment is committed  to every single activity, which means that the data is being loaded every time a new activity is created. So what I want is to show the same fragment to all activities, without loading the data over and over again.

Comment: @Enve, Can your data in the fragment be passed as extras? I see that your main concern is the data not being pinged again and again from the server, so why not pass  the data as extra. You can even pass the whole response which you have received from the server as an extra. If you are even receiving images from the server, you can save the images temporarily on the SD card, and pass the path of the image to every activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragments belong to only one activity. After you `commit()` the transaction, that fragment "belongs" to that activity.

If you want a higher level sharing or network related data, I suggest you to implement it in a [`Bound Service`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) and have activities or fragments to get this data directly from the `Service`

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one activity in your application, it is possible.  But you cant show the loaded fragment in many activities.

Only after adding the fragment to the container, you can attach and detach a fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cache data using Fragment, but as you can see at documentation:

> A Fragment **represents a behavior or a portion of user interface** in an
>   Activity

source: [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)
Fragment should be used to avoid **"copy-paste"** in user interface code.

But you are trying to **cache the data** from network. This is not *mission* of **Fragment**. This is not **Tier** when you should *process data*. At **Fragment** you should only load already cached data.

I can recomend you choose one of next solutions:
**1). Use SQLite database to cache data.**
If you want to cache data in SQLite, I recomend you use pattern, which *Virgil Dobjanschi* described at **Google I/O conference** in 2010(link to video [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE))
Also, I think [this](https://github.com/Udinic/SyncAdapter) example may be helpful for implementing this pattern.

**2). Use some network libraries, which can help you to cache data**

**Robospice** - is a modular android library that makes writing asynchronous long running tasks easy. It is specialized in network requests, **supports caching** and offers REST requests out-of-the box using extension modules.
link: [Robospice](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice)
example project: [Robospice+Retrofit](https://github.com/octo-online/RoboSpice-samples/tree/release/robospice-sample-retrofit)
**Short description how to cache:**

```
getSpiceManager().execute(githubRequest, "github", DurationInMillis.ONE_MINUTE, new ListContributorRequestListener());
```

`"github"` - is a key. `DurationInMillis.ONE_MINUTE` - time while cached data will be actual. This means, that if you are executed this request first time, data will be loaded from network. If you are executed this request **second time during 1 minute**, then data will be loaded from local cache.
Possible values of `DurationInMillis` from [docs](http://stephanenicolas.github.io/robospice/site/latest/apidocs/com/octo/android/robospice/persistence/DurationInMillis.html):

```
**Field Summary**

static long ALWAYS 
          Deprecated.

static long ALWAYS_EXPIRED 
          Data in cache will never be returned, a network call will always be performed.

static long ALWAYS_RETURNED 
          Data in cache will always be returned.

static long NEVER 
          Deprecated. 

static long ONE_DAY 

static long ONE_HOUR 

static long ONE_MINUTE 

static long ONE_SECOND 

static long ONE_WEEK
```

**OkHttp** - from [docs](http://square.github.io/okhttp/):
OkHttp is an HTTP client that’s efficient by default:

- HTTP/2 and SPDY support allows all requests to the same host to share
  a socket.
- Connection pooling reduces request latency (if SPDY isn’t
  available).
- Transparent GZIP shrinks download sizes.
- **Response caching avoids the network completely for repeat requests.**

link: [OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp)
example project: [samples](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/samples/simple-client)
**Short description how to cache:**

```
// Create an HTTP client that uses a cache on the file system. Android applications should use
    // their Context to get a cache directory.
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    File cacheDir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    HttpResponseCache cache = new HttpResponseCache(cacheDir, 1024);
    okHttpClient.setResponseCache(cache);
```

**Full example** [here](https://gist.github.com/swankjesse/5889518)